# Zend Gdata - setVisibility for newEventEntry? (specify events for multiple calendars)

Tags: php, zend-framework, calendar

I know that you can use setVisibility('private-abcdefg') for newEventQuery() in order to specify a particular calendar.

My question is, can I use the same concept for newEventEntry()?

$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

```
 $newEvent = $gdataCal->newEventEntry();

 $newEvent->setVisibility('private-******************');
```

I tried out this code, but I receive the error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getDOM() on a non-object in /home/content/b/e/h/behrk2/html/ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library/Zend/Gdata/Kind/EventEntry.php on line 154
```

Is there anything I can do to accomplish this? Because I have multiple Google Calendar's in one account, and I would like to specify which Calendar an event should go to...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it. I had the same exact problem, and it's simple, but not obvious, and took me some digging through the documentation to notice. To post to a calendar other than the default calendar, just add the uri to the other calendar to the insertEvent function at the end, like so:

```
$createdEvent = $gdataCal->insertEvent($newEvent, $uri);
```